# Changes to event create hundreds of email bounce backs for addresses that are not participants

Tags: google-calendar

I have a team shared calendar who I am the owner to. There is a meeting which has been scheduled from 2021 which is still existing and running. Obviously there are people who have left the organization in that time. I went ahead and updated the invitee list and don't see them as an invitee anymore but still whenever I make changes to that calendar I receive 100's of emails stating that the email is inactive. I made a list of all the inactive invitees to double check my calendar invite and delete them but I cannot even find them on the list. Please help me

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications](/tour). Please [edit] your question to clarify the following: **1.** What is a team shared calendar? Do you mean you have a Google Calendar that is shared with other employees or do you mean something else?  **2.** Are you talking about a recurring meeting? **3.** I assume you are talking about a Google Workspace (GWS) account. **4.** Are you changing an occurrence of the event or all occurrences? **5.** Is there any reason you can't recreate the event with the right attendees and delete this one? **6.** Have you asked your company's GWS admin for help?

Comment: Also, is it possible that one of the participant addresses is a distribution list? If all the participants are internal the GWS admin can look into that for you.